# Code fails in jQuery 2.1.4 but works well in older versions

Tags: jquery

I have noticed that my code does not work in jQuery 2.1.4. but works in jquery 1.4.3. I have made a code through which checking a main checkbox checks all the checkbox in the table. The code works for the first 2 click but does not work from 3 rd click .
The code works correctly when i use jquery 1.4.3.
The jquery code is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mainCheckBox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#pageTbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("checked", true);
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#pageTbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("checked", false);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

can somebody give the solution why it fails on newest jquery version?

Comment: Use `$(this).prop("checked", false);`

Comment: Relevant: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ There have been release notes for every release of jQuery on [their blog](http://blog.jquery.com/) as well.

Comment: changed the code to use prop instead of attr and my problem is now solved. Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

```
$(this).prop("checked", true/false);
```

Existing code can be optimized as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainCheckBox").change(function () {
        $("#pageTbody input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

1. no need to use `.each()`
2. use `change` event instead of `click`

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is a property and not an attribute, so You will have to use `.prop` now in order to get it right:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mainCheckBox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#pageTbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#pageTbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
$(this).prop("checked", true);
```